# Hibernate noob - retrieve partial object

Tags: nhibernate

Greetings!

I have the following class and at times need to retrieve only title and subTitle elements:

```
public class Article implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID;
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String subTitle;
    private String body;
    ....
}
```

What's the best way to facilitate this? I thought about making title and subTitle stand alone objects but I honestly don't know what I'm doing yet.

I have the luxury of changing the entire composition of Article, but asking first is the most sensible thing for me at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this?  Why does it matter if Hibernate loads the extra fields?  You're not required to use them.

Comment: ... in all honesty, it seems very counter intuitive to be loading everything when I need only a few bits. In practical terms I could load the whole thing, but then I'm thinking performance and scale, at least in theory.

Comment: Not returning those fields is not going to affect performance. Worry about the functionality of your application, not making a 0.001 second query run 0.000000000001 second faster.

Comment: ... hm, premature optimization?!?

Comment: ... Phill, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll at least vote it up, or accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate every simple property with LAZY -> just like this @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

So, it will be loaded only if you need

Comment: That's the Java version, although the concept still applies (`lazy="true"` in the mappings)

Answer (score 1):

Provided this is for displaying purpose, you could also rely on a ResultTransformer.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660820/using-unmapped-class-with-nhibernate-named-query/662725#662725) which deals with similar problem and limits the retrieved properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this by creating a specific class to hold the information you want, then you import it in your mapping. See [5.1.19.import](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-import) in the manual. I believe you can use the imported class in your HQL, like this:

```
"select new Titles(a.title, a.subTitle) from Article a where a.id = :id"
```

Here's a blog post I found on this subject: http://gustavoringel.blogspot.com/2009/02/creating-dto-in-nhibernate-hql-using.html.

Good luck!